# How to manage multiple function return types in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a method like the following:

```
abstract canDeactivate() : boolean | Promise<boolean>;
```

How can I manage the promise implementation of the method and the boolean implementation in the caller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a type guard to distinguish between the two cases:

```
abstract class Target {
    abstract canDeactivate() : boolean | Promise<boolean>;
}

declare let t: Target
var r = t.canDeactivate();
if (typeof r === 'boolean') { // type guard
    r // boolean
} else {
    r.then(v=> v)// r is Promise<bool>
}
```

Comment: But if the method can return also an observable? `canDeactivate() : boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean>`

Comment: @GiuseppeNotarnicola same principle applies, you still need to use a type guard. you can use an `in` typeguard or an `instanceof` typeguard on the else in the `if` above